# Can I prevent maven from resolving local dependancies?

Tags: maven

This is to test that the remote maven repository I setup is functioning correctly, I would like to stop maven looking locally (./m2) for jars and only ever source them from the remote repo. Any ideas on how to achieve this appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply delete you .m2/repository.

Otherwise, when you build your project, you can use the -U option to update the snapshots.

You can also use the maven dependency plugin with this : dependency:purge-local-repository . You will find more detail on the webpage of the plugin : http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [post](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html) related to purging project dependencies and and re resolving them.
Deleting `.m2` is not a good option as you will be deleting all other jars also and you have do it every time.
`-U` option will force an update every time, that might also be suitable for you.

Comment: -U is forcing update for ONLY snapshots, for which I believe is not that valuable for what OP is looking for